# Necessary ports to talk to a validator (devnet) for deployment

Tags: anchor, devnet, deploy

I teach at a university where I plan to introduce students to Solana blockchain development. I can deploy programs normally to devnet when running my laptop at home (anchor deploy), but when connected through the university network the same laptop/solana install always stay at 0.0%, retries 5 times and expires. Querying account balance with "solana balance" works normally. It seems that deployment uses ports that are blocked by the University firewall. What are the ports that should be opened in the University firewall to make it work? Are there other options that doesn't need to open non-standard ports? Like deploying using only standard SSL ports etc?

Answer (score 1):

Program deployment makes use of a few connections, making it pretty complicated. To send the transactions, the tool uses QUIC, which is built on top of UDP, so perhaps outgoing UDP is blocked.

Otherwise, transaction confirmation goes through WSS, which is just built on TCP, which should be ok.

So be sure to check on the UDP settings first.